# Parent methods which return child class instances

Tags: python, class, oop

Is it bad practice, and if so, why, to return instances of child classes as output of methods of an instance of the parent class?

For example, can the following --

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr = attr

    def child(self, typ):
        if typ == 'a':
            return ChildA(self.attr)
        else:
            return ChildB(self.attr)

class ChildA(Parent):
    pass

class ChildB(Parent):
    pass
```

be a good design?

Comment: Isn't this a matter of opinion? We're not known for having opinions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I was thinking that questions about "what is a good practice", with respect to software design, are acceptable. Search for "good practice" in SO and you'll find quite a lot of high-voted questions, even if it is not always clear that there is a definitive answer.

Comment: Most of those are from "the old" Stack Overflow, and most (should) have been closed.

Answer (score 5):

I would appreciate if someone more knowledgeable answers this question, but as this has yet to happen, I'll throw in my two cents' worth.

---

I think that it's indeed not good practice. Parent classes shouldn't directly reference child classes for a number of reasons:

- First and foremost, it impedes future extensions of the module. Whenever a new child class is introduced, it would probably require updating the parent class as well in order to take this new child class into account in its implementation. This breaks the [open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) of the [SOLID principles of object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).
- Another drawback, at least in *Python*, is that it forces all child classes to be defined in the same file, in order to avoid circular imports.
- Furthermore, since the specified method is inherited by the child classes, then unless it's overridden, it triggers some kind of familiarity between "brother" classes, which might not be desired.

Although the technical issues may be circumvented with some coding effort, this approach unnecessarily places another burden on the programmer.

I'm sure that there are certain situations where it would seem useful for a parent class to be made aware of its child classes, however I think that in general, such situations infer an error in design and an alternative solution that doesn't involve this kind of introspection should be sought after.

Note that this doesn't mean parent objects shouldn't utilize child objects. Child objects, like all other objects, may be legitimately received as arguments or returned by their parent's methods. The parent's methods may even treat them as ordinary parent objects since a child object is also a parent object and that's one of the main pillars of object-oriented programming.

---

Regarding your particular example, consider the [factory design pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html). For example:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr = attr

class ChildA(Parent):
    pass

class ChildB(Parent):
    pass

class Factory(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def create(self, <some_external_data>):
        if <an algorithm that determines the desired type based
            on some_external_data and the state of the parent>:
            return ChildA(parent.attr)
        else:
            return ChildB(parent.attr)
```

Comment: In my case, I want to create a factory pattern for file parsers, problem is I don't know typ which you passed on create method, the thing is the Parent class "Parser" has this function that decide what is the type of file based on extension retrieval, Where should I define this method? In Factory class? I think it is invalid as It should be in Parser class itself, Can you please guide @yoel?

Comment: Firstly, the factory class could either receive the parent object in its `__init__()` method or in its `create()` method. Then, in its `create()` method, it shall invoke a parent's method to retrieve the extension. Finally, in its `create()` method, it shall determine the desired type of the child using some algorithm that is based on the retrieved extension.